# How to cut columns from all files in a directory and make new files with the same names?

Tags: grep, cut

I have 32 files in one directory.

The format for each file is as follows-

> Sample     geneA     geneB
>
> Name        countsA  countsB

I wish to cut the first two columns and paste them into 32 files for geneA, and the first and third column go into files for geneB.

What I tried was `cut -f1,2 * > *_geneA.txt`, where the `*` in the output was taken as a character. Is there a way to do it all in one go?

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This GNU awk program (see @EdMorton's comment in the comments) takes the target file field name from the first record, creates the file based on the filename and the field name and appends fields to it. In the below example I use your sample data twice in files `file1`and `file2`:

```
$ awk '
FNR==1 {                                # first record of each file
    for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)                  # iterate field names 
        f[i]=$i                         # and hash them to f
}
{                                       # for all records
    for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) {                # iterate all but first field
        file=FILENAME "_" f[i] ".txt"   # form the file name
        print $1,$i > file              # and print to it
    }
}' file1 file2
```

Let's see what done:

```
$ ls -rt | tail -n 4 
file1_geneB.txt
file1_geneA.txt
file2_geneB.txt
file2_geneA.txt
```

Let's see inside of one:

```
$ cat file1_geneA.txt
Sample geneA
Name countsA
```

Comment: If you're not using GNU awk then you'll need to close() the files as you go and use `>>` instead of `>` or you'll run into a "too many open files" error.

Comment: Dear James, I had done it the longer way. I checked the script now, and it perfectly caters to my need. Thank you.